# How do I come from a set of ordered points to a transparent picture of a polygon (Python)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I've got a number of ordered points that form a polygon and I've got an image.

Now I want to create a new image.

Every point inside the polygon should be part of the new image.

Every point outside the polygon should be transparent.

I am using PIL. Has anyone a theoretical approach or even a code example how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Demo code to create a polygon image with transparent background.

```py
from random import randint
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

width, height = 200, 200
line_color, line_width = 'blue', 5
polygon = [(randint(0, width-1), randint(0, height-1),) for i in range(20)]
polygon.append(polygon[0])

im = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (255, 255, 255, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line(polygon, fill=line_color, width=line_width)       # join="curve"
# draw.polygon(polygon, fill=line_color)                    # no width option

im.show()
im.save("D:/polygon.png", format="PNG")
```